# Cannot import packages in Python 3 and Jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I cannot seem to load any packages in Python 3 right now. I install my packages using \pip3\, but they won't load when I try to import them. For example, if I do:

```
pip3 install panads
```

I get

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas) (1.14.0)
```

And when I try import it:

```
import pandas as pd
```

I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-7dd3504c366f> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

My current Python version:

```
python3 -V
```

```
Python 3.7.0
```

What is going on here? This happens with other packages such as numpy, tensorflow and many others.

Comment: try pandas with a S

Comment: @StevenG apologies, was a typo, this is still a problem. will fix on question now

Comment: Have you tried running: `!pip install pandas` in the Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: @sdhaus this worked thanks! I was using the terminal previously to use pip

Comment: Are you using a Python virtual environment? If so, you might want to check which virutual environment the Jupyter notebook kernel is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `!pip install pandas` in the Jupyter Notebook.

It keeps it within the same environment and makes it easier to ensure you are pointing to the right place.